# Java Operators : |= bitwise OR and assign example

Tags: java, operators, bit-manipulation, variable-assignment

I just going through code someone has written and I saw `|=` usage, looking up on Java operators, it suggests bitwise or and assign operation, can anyone explain and give me an example of it?

Here is the code that read it:

```
    for (String search : textSearch.getValue())
         matches |= field.contains(search);
```

Comment: Could *you* show us the code you read?

Comment: @talnicolas: updated question with code .

Comment: What is the type of `matches`? `int` or `boolean`?

Comment: see my answer, probably bitwise-or is not meant at all here!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
a |= b;
```

is the same as

```
a = (a | b);
```

It calculates the **bitwise OR** of the two operands, and **assigns** the result to the left operand.

To explain your example code:

```
for (String search : textSearch.getValue())
    matches |= field.contains(search);
```

I presume `matches` is a `boolean`; this means that the bitwise operators behave the same as logical operators.

On each iteration of the loop, it `OR`s the current value of `matches` with whatever is returned from `field.contains()`. This has the effect of setting it to `true` if it was already true, **or** if `field.contains()` returns true.

So, it calculates if **any** of the calls to `field.contains()`, throughout the entire loop, has returned `true`.

Comment: can you put in some values for a and b?

Comment: oh ok, now it make some sense

Comment: "this means that the bitwise operators behave the same as logical operators". Actually, logical operators will short-circuit. Short circuiting is probably desired here.

Comment: It should also be noted that if `contains()` has no side-effects, this is rather inefficient.  Adding at least an `if (matches) { break; }` inside the loop would be so much nicer...  (Although I suppose `getValue()` may be returning so few searches that it won't make a noticeable difference...)

Answer (score 13):

`a |= b` is the same as `a = (a | b)`

**Boolean Variables**

In a `boolean` context, it means:

```
if (b) {
    a = true;
}
```

that is, if `b` is true then `a` will be true, otherwise `a` will be unmodified.

**Bitwise Operations**

In a bit wise context it means that every binary bit that's set in `b` will become set in `a`.  Bits that are clear in `b` will be unmodified in `a`.

So if bit 0 is set in `b`, it'll also become set in `a`, per the example below:

- This will *set* the bottom bit of an integer:

  `a |= 0x01`
- This will *clear* the bottom bit:

  `a &= ~0x01`
- This will *toggle* the bottom bit:

  `a ^= 0x01;`

Comment: can put in some number values for a and explain the detail ooperation.

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
int i = 5;
i |= 10;
```

is equivalent to this code:

```
int i = 5;
i = i | 10;
```

Similarly, this code:

```
boolean b = false;
b |= true;
```

is equivalent to this one:

```
boolean b = false;
b = b | true;
```

In the first example, a bit-wise OR is being performed. In the second example, a boolean OR is performed.

Answer (score 2):

`a |= b` is the same as `a = a | b`

`a | b` is a bitwise operator if both operands are integral types (int, short, etc...).  *If both operands are booleans, then its is a boolean or.*

When both `a` and `b` are booleans, the difference between `a | b` and `a || b` is that in the first, both sides are *always* evaluated, in the later `b` is only evaluated if `a` is false.  It is sort of a "shortcut" operator.

This is useful for situations like this:

```
if (a == null || a.equals(b)) { .. do something .. } // works

if (a == null | a.equals(b)) { .. do something .. } // NPE if a is null
```

On the other hand, `||` actually is implemented as another conditional jump in the bytecode/machine-code.  In some cases, it may be faster to evaluate boolean conditions using the `|` operator to avoid the additional jump (and thus branch predition, etc...).  Definitely something for low-level micro-benchmarking to figure out which is better (and usually not important in most applications).

When you do `a |= b` you are always evaluating both `a` and `b`.  It doesn't really make sense to have an `a ||= b` operators, since the equivalent `a = a || b` would translate to:

```
if (a) a = true;
else if (b) a = true
else a = false;
```

...due to the conditional nature of `||` evaluation.  In other words, `b` would not be evaluated if `a` was already true.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be possible that the code has a bug and it was meant

`matches = matches || field.contains(search);`

so that matches should be `true` if at least one field contains the `search` variable?

Comment: your code is not functionally the same - if `matches` is already true then the short circuit operator will prevent evaluation of `field.contains(search)`.  AFAIK the `|=` operator won't do that.

Comment: Which means my code is optimization of the original code

Comment: only if it's truly intended that `.contains()` is not called in those circumstances.

Comment: you mean if the `.contains()` method does not have side-effects

Comment: yeah, mostly - in this case it probably doesn't matter, but it's worth knowing that for boolean variables `a |= func()` is the same as `a = a | func()` which is not functionally the same as `a = a || func()`, even though the end result on `a` is the same.

Answer (score 0):

That code snippet is a poor example of when to use that operator.  Honestly I can't think of a great example of when to use this operator, but here's my best attempt:

```
boolean somethingIsTrue = testSomethingTrue();
if(somethingIsTrue){
    //Do something
}
somethingIsTrue |= testSomethingElseTrue();
if(somethingIsTrue){
    //Do something else
}
somethingIsTrue |= testSomethingElseTrue2();
if(somethingIsTrue){
    //Do something else than something or something else
}
```

**Note:**  You need 3 ifs because otherwise you could just do `somethingIsTrue | testSomethingElseTrue()` for the second if.

---

In case you were wondering why you shouldn't use the operator in the first example, here's why:

From a performance standpoint, it is poor because it does a compare and an assign for each loop instead of just a compare.  Also, it continues iterating even when future iterations will have no effect (once `matches` gets set to `true` it will not change, and `String.contains` has no side effects).

It is also poor from a readability standpoint, based solely on the existence of this question ;)

Thus, in place of that snippet I'd go for:

```
for (String search : textSearch.getValue()){
    if(field.contains(search)){
        matches = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

On a side note, it seems to me like the original coder might have been playing a *bit* too much [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) when (s)he wrote this :)

Comment: There are many good use cases for this operator. Imagine methods like `addAll` or `removeAll` in a set, provided that you iterate over the collection in parameter. You `add` or `remove` in a loop, and you want to return `true` if you actually added or removed at least one entry.