# Java Syntax- What does |= mean

Tags: java, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Operators : `|= bitwise OR and assign` example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142059/java-operators-bitwise-or-and-assign-example)

what does |= mean in Java?

For example below;

---

note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Always go here first: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html.

It's the bitwise-or assignment operator.

It's the same as:

```
note.flags = note.flags | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```