# Why using '|'  in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Operators : `|= bitwise OR and assign` example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142059/java-operators-bitwise-or-and-assign-example)

```
boolean bAlive;

bAlive |= this.properties.containsKey(name);
```

In the above , the code uses `'|'`. 
Why using `'|`' ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try accepting the answers if u find yourself satisfied according to your question...

Answer (score 5):

The boolean is being OR'ed with the value on the right.

If `this.properties.containsKey(name)` is `TRUE`, then `bAlive` is set to `TRUE`.

Otherwise, `bAlive` remains the same.