# Logic of Java Operators && and ||

Tags: java, if-statement, operators

Hello dear Programmers,

I have a String `String input = "30.09.1993";`
Then i want to save all numbers in this string in an array(Only numbers!). The "." are at index 2 and 5 so i want to skip these parts of my string in my loop with an if-statement.

I fixed my problem and everything works fine but I'm confused with the logic of the `&&` and `||` operators.

This is my working code:

```
String input = "30.09.1993";
int[] eachNumbers = new int[8];

int x = 0;
for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
    if(i != 2 && i != 5){
       eachNumbers[x] = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(i, i+1));
       x++;
    }
}
```

And this is the code which doesnt work:

```
String input = "30.09.1993";
int[] eachNumbers = new int[8];

int x = 0;
for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
    if(i != 2 || i != 5){
       eachNumbers[x] = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(i, i+1));
       x++;
    }
}
```

The only difference between these two code snippets are the operators in the if-clause.

I thought that the results for these operators are:

**`&&` operator:**

```
false + false = false
true  + false = false
false + true  = false
true  + true  = true
```

**`||` operator:**

```
false + false = false
true  + false = true
false + true  = true
true  + true  = true
```

So in my opinion the second code snippet should work and the first should throw a `NumberFormatException`. But thats not the case.

I'm sure there are some better solutions for what im doing but my question is only about the logic in my if-statement. Can someone explain me the logic behind this? I'm totally confused and thankful for every helping answer.

Greetings
Lukas Warsitz

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the second snippet, the if-clause will always be true, because `i` will always be not 2 or not 5 (because it cannot be 2 and 5 at the same time)

For what you want to do your first snippet is fine, it does exactly what you want: If your are not at the third element and neither at the 6th element, you want to parse, else you are at one of the points in the date.

Comment: After thinking a while about your answer i understood it, thank you very much for the fast answer!

Answer (score 3):

**Key point is here :**  **In && if first case is false, second case won't check.**

```
true && false // Evaluates false because the second is false 
false && true // Evaluates false because the first is false 
true && true // Evaluates true because both are true 
false && false // Evaluates false because the first is false
```

and

**In || if first case is true , second case won't check.**

```
true || false // Evaluates true because the first is true 
false || true // Evaluates true because the second is true 
true || true // Evaluates true because the first is true
false || false // Evaluates false because both are false
```

Comment: "false && false // Evaluates false because both are false" - is not true. because the first one is false , so the second one is untested

Answer (score 3):

Although not necessarily your issue which LionC notes.

the 4 and and or logic operators follow the following logic:

**&** is as you describe && above.

```
false + false = false
true  + false = false
false + true  = false
true  + true  = true
```

**|** is as you describe `||` above

```
false + false = false
true  + false = true
false + true  = true
true  + true  = true
```

&& and || are shortcut operators that don't test the second value if it would make no difference to the result.

**&&**

```
false + untested = false
true  + false = false
false + untested = false
true  + true  = true
```

**||**

```
false + false = false
true  + untested = true
false + true  = true
true  + untested  = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second snippet is not working because it should be

```
if(i != 2 && i != 5)
```

and your first snippet is not throwing error because of same reason that you have used && there.

Comment: You told me everything i knew before.. but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Pick a number, *any number*. It is either not equal 2, or not equal 5.

Therefore the expression `(i != 2 || i != 5)` can be statically (by the compiler) transformed into just `true` and the whole `if` control structure eliminated.

The obvious result is a `NumberFormatException` if *any* of the characters is not a digit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not giving answer for your question but suggesting better code.

```
public class splitToArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "30.09.1993";    
        input = input.replace(".", " ");
        String array[] = input.split(" ");
        for(String value : array){
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}

Output:
30
09
1993
```

Now use `Integer.parseInt` to get integer value. This will also work when you have `String input = "30.9.1993";` [0 removed from `09`]

Comment: Thanks for your advice but i need to create a digit sum from the birthdate, thats why i need every single number.

Answer (score 1):

`i` can only have one value at a time.
So any of the following conditions are valid:

```
if(i != 2 && i != 5) //means `i` is not any 2 AND i is not 5
```

or

```
if(i == 2 || i == 5) //means `i` is either 2 OR 5
```

Note: `(i != 2 || i != 5)` is always true because at any time

> 1. If i = 2, LHS `i is not equal to 2` is FALSE and RHS `i is not equal to 5` is TRUE
> 2. If i = 5, LHS `i is not equal to 2` is TRUE and RHS `i is not equal to 5` is FALSE
> 3. For all other value of i: Both LHS and RHS are true.

Comment: "|" does not stand for OR :)

Comment: @rookieB it does stands for OR, but [bitwise OR](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10142098/2982225), not for logical OR ;) thanks for noticing :)

Comment: well i don't see you are using bitwise OR as i thought it was a typo